# Wrap MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() in a help method/property?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
private string MethodName
{
   get
   {
      MethodBase m = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
      return String.Format("{0}.{1}", m.ReflectedType.Name, m.Name);
   }
}
```

I'd like to do something like this but of course now the call is made from a different method to the one I want to describe. Is there a simple way around this or an obvious alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the `StackTrace` doing something like:

```
string MethodName
{
    get
    {
        return new StackTrace()
                    .GetFrame(1) // Get previous frame because we want to know the calling method name
                    .GetMethod()
                    .Name;
    }
}
```